# How do I load and breakdown Firestore documents based on location

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation, flutter-layout

In my app, I have the ability for users to post content in a public community forum. How do I break down posts based on the neighborhood users are in so user can only see posts from people in their same neighborhood, block, etc.

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+nearby or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bflutter%5D+nearby?

Comment: Is there a question on how to do it in flutter?

Comment: The second link in my comment is only questions about Flutter.